# How to dynamically update Flask template when user likes a post?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I have simple blog based webpage where you can like posts, but when the like_action happened it refresh the whole page, and it is really bad when you were already at the bottom of the page. So basically I just want to refresh a portion of the html.

I read a lot about ajax, but when a tried to implement it didn't work really well :(

```py
@posts.route('/like/<int:post_id>/<action>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def like_action(post_id, action):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(id=post_id).first_or_404()
    if action == 'like':
        current_user.like_post(post)
        db.session.commit()
    if action == 'unlike':
        current_user.unlike_post(post)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('section.html', post = post)
```

```html
<div class="likes" id="result{{post.id}}">
  <hr>
  {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if current_user.has_liked_post(post) %}
      <a class="updateButton" post_id="{{post.id}}" href="{{ url_for('posts.like_action', post_id=post.id, action='unlike') }}"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='heart-filled.png')}}" style="width:5%; height:5%;"></a>
    {% else %}
      <a class="updateButton" post_id="{{post.id}}" href="{{ url_for('posts.like_action', post_id=post.id, action='like') }}"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='heart-no-fill.png')}}" style="width:5%; height:5%;"></a>
    {% endif %}
  {% else %}
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='heart-no-fill.png')}}" style="width:5%; height:5%;">
  {% endif %}
  <small>{{post.likes.count()}}</small>
</div>
```

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('click','.updateButton', function(){

          var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');

          req = $.ajax({
            url:'/like/<int:post_id>/<action>'
            type:'POST'
            data: {id:post_id}
          });

          req.done(function(data){
            $('result'+post_id).html(data);
          });

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just my concept. It will give you idea on how you can go about with it.

You can see how I attached the like and unlike to id attributes so that I can post it as ajax

```
 <a class="unlike" id="unlike_{{post.id}}" href="{{ url_for('posts.like_action', post_id=post.id, action='unlike') }}"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='heart-filled.png')}}" style="width:5%; height:5%;"></a>
  

      <a class="like" id="like_{{post.id}}" href="{{ url_for('posts.like_action', post_id=post.id, action='like') }}"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='heart-no-fill.png')}}" style="width:5%; height:5%;"></a>
```

Here you can the pass the postid as post_id1 and action as likeunlike

Hence you can have something like

```
if likeunlike == 'like':
        current_user.like_post(post)
        db.session.commit()
    if likeunlike == 'unlike':
        current_user.unlike_post(post)
```

here is how you ajax script may look like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // like and unlike click
    $(".like, .unlike").click(function(){
        var id = this.id;   // Getting Button id
        var split_id = id.split("_");

        var text = split_id[0];
        var post_id1 = split_id[1];  // postid

       

        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ur-url',
            type: 'post',
            data: {post_id1:post_id1,likeunlike:text},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                //var likes = data['likes'];
                //var unlikes = data['unlikes'];

                $("#likes_"+post_id).html(data);        // setting likes
                $("#unlikes_"+post_id).html(data);    // setting unlikes
    

            }
            
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Thx a lot! I will try it as soo  as Im in front of the computer, one question, what should I return in the like_action func. the rendered template or jsonify?

Comment: you can try both but jsonify will be okay. if u will be using jsonify or json.dumps({'unlike': unlike value, 'like': like value here}) then in your ajax. datatype should be json not html eg dataType: 'json',

Comment: THANK YOU after 3days finally got it! Cheers l!

Comment: Am glad I could help you on this. its more easier to do via reactjs + redux, vuejs or angular6+. All i normally do is just post the data and retrieve the response via json and then allow any of my frontend listed above to handle it. i guess  you should also try working with frontend javascript. it makes things faster and easier

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax `.done()` function you should change this:

```
$('result'+post_id).html(data)
```

to this one

```
$('#result'+post_id).html(data)
```

because in jQuery you have to add `#` to the first of your queries for `id`

Comment: Thx! But it is still not working, the like_action() returns the whole snippet section as a full html, and not the part of the main html :(

Comment: @MarkKiraly you need to return `json` object instead of whole HTML inside of your `def like_action(...)`